# Is the following matrix in reduced row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: for row echelon form, the leading coefficient of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it.

Comment: @Tanner, But can a row have no leading entry, "1". This is the case of second row. I am asking that can a matrix containing a row with no leading entry of "1" be considered reduced REF?

Comment: For a matrix to be in [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#rref), it must be in row echelon form.

Comment: Oh, I had missed that. The leading entry "4" from the second row is on the right of "1" the leading entry in in the third row. So the matrix in not in REF form, and hence not reduced REF. correct?

Answer (score 2):

Is is not even in row echelon form.

You need to swap rows two and three to get
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
which is in row echelon form.

To obtain the reduced row echelon form, the new third row needs to be divided by $4$ and subtracted from the second and first rows $5$ and $1$ times, respectively, to obtain
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This is the reduced row echelon form of your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix to be in [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#rref), it must be in row echelon form.

For a matrix to be in row echelon form, the leading coefficient of a nonzero row

must be always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it.

Therefore, your matrix is not in reduced row echelon form.